# Not able to talk to Amazon SimpleDB from android using mobile SDK

Tags: android, amazon-simpledb

I am following amazon samples that they distributed with android SDK. I am doing almost exactly same thing in my app, but I am getting following exception:

```
I/SSLSocketFactory(  967): Using factory org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl@40062b40
I/SSLSocketFactory(  967): Using factory org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl@40062b40
W/HttpClient(  967): Unable to execute HTTP request: sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
I/SSLSocketFactory(  967): Using factory org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl@40062b40
W/HttpClient(  967): Unable to execute HTTP request: sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
I/SSLSocketFactory(  967): Using factory org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl@40062b40
W/HttpClient(  967): Unable to execute HTTP request: sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
I/SSLSocketFactory(  967): Using factory org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl@40062b40
W/HttpClient(  967): Unable to execute HTTP request: sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
E/Guild::createMessageItem: (  967): java.net.UnknownHostException: sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Here is my request:

```
I/com.amazonaws.request(  967): Sending Request: POST https://sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com / Parameters: (Attribute.3.Value: t9, Attribute.4.Name: created_by, SignatureMethod: asdedd, Attribute.5.Value: 2011-03-22 20:51:20, AWSAccessKeyId:<acccessid>, Attribute.1.Name: message_id, Attribute.3.Name: description, Timestamp: 2011-03-23T00:51:21.170Z, Signature: <securitycode>, Attribute.6.Name: modified, Attribute.2.Name: title, Attribute.2.Value: t3, Action: PutAttributes, ItemName: x1300841480654, DomainName: messages, Attribute.1.Value: x1300841480654, Attribute.6.Value: 2011-03-22 20:51:20, Version: 2009-04-15, SignatureVersion: 2, Attribute.5.Name: created, Attribute.4.Value: x@yahoo.com, )
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is what I am missing, in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```